# How to find props of a component in jest when it's connected component has updated?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

I'm using `jest` and `enzyme` for testing my react app. I've a connected component which has 1 hoc over it (`connectWithActions`) and `connect` from react-redux. With `connectWithActions`, I provide `setState`, `dispatch` and `getState`. I use this `HOC` as :

```
compose(
    connectActions(Handlers),
    connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps),
)(MyComponent)
```

My handlers look like:

```
const Handlers = {
    Handler1: (action, {getState, setState, dispatch}) => {
        setState({newStateValue: action.payload.value})
    }
}
```

this `setState` is the `setState` which react provides to the component. (through HOC)

Now `MyComponent` has updated props with `newStateValue` in it.

So, In jest:
I've `mounted` my `composedComponent` (connected) and I'm simulating the action which would trigger `Handler1` and will set the state as :

```
test('test...', () => {
    const node = Component.find('.className');
    node.simulate('click');

    //how do I check that state is updated??
    console.log(Component.find('MyComponent').props());
  });
```

but I'm not able to figure out how do I `test` this. I tried checking props but I don't have any `newStateValue`.

Comment: Did you try to `mount` your subject instead of `shallowing` it? Or try to use `mycomponent.instance().props()` instead ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following piece of code worked for me:

```
test('test...', () => {
    const node = Component.find('.className');
    node.simulate('click');

    Component.update();

    expect(Component.find(MyComponent).props(). newStateValue).toEqual(desiredValue);
  });
```